# Выборка результата из массива

Tags: javascript, html

Есть html страница на которой есть выпадающий список

```
<div class="new-select-style-wpandyou">
    <select id="sel" required size="1" name="path">
        <option selected value>Выберите карту</option>
        <option value="АХО">АХО</option>
        <option value="СБ">Cлужба безопасности</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

и необходимо сделать так что бы когда выбираем одно из значений из массива выдало результат в другой селект: Сам массив

```
var WordsData = [
            ["АХО", ["Прочее", "Ремонт", "Эликтричество"]],
            ["СБ", ["Мошеничество","Видеокамера","Хищение"]]
        ];
```

Прошу оказать помощь в решении проблемы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var WordsData = {
  "АХО": ["Прочее", "Ремонт", "Эликтричество"],
  "СБ": ["Мошеничество", "Видеокамера", "Хищение"]
};
$("#sel").change(function() {
  $('.select2').empty();
  var x = $(this).val();
  var text = '';
  for (var inx = 0; inx < WordsData[x].length; inx++) {
    text += '<option>' + WordsData[x][inx] + '</option>';
  }
  $('.select2').append(text);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="new-select-style-wpandyou">
  <select id="sel" required size="1" name="path">
    <option selected value>Выберите карту</option>
    <option value="АХО">АХО</option>
    <option value="СБ">Cлужба безопасности</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select class="select2">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо добрый человек, дай бог тебе здоровья

Comment: @Павел )) удачи...

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно создать 2 select на странице, только один из них скрыть. В первом select всем пунктам нужно дать свой идентификатор (value). Дальше вам нужно будет написать код на javascript, чтобы при выборе значения в первом select у вас появлялся второй select, и в зависимости от выбранного пункта (точнее его value) чтобы подставлялись данные во второй select.

Пример получения данных из select:

```js
 $( "select" )
      .change(function() {
        var str = "";
        $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
          str += $( this ).text() + " ";
        });
        $( "div" ).text( str );
      })
      .trigger( "change" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
      <option>Flowers</option>
      <option selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
      <option>Trees</option>
      <option>Bushes</option>
      <option>Grass</option>
      <option>Dirt</option>
    </select>
    <div></div>
```

Comment: это то я понял, но вот у меня заминка с jq я не могу понять как правильно вызвать что бы всё это отображалось корректно

Comment: вот вам пример как получить данные из select, только нужно добавить еще один select, в js коде сделать его появление при выборе значения из первого select.

Comment: А я понял, когда у меня выбрано допустим АХО то отобразить Селекты с результатами ахо так?

Comment: Вам можно вместо АХО в value написать цифры. Например <option value="1">АХО</option>. И дальше при выборе пункта с value 1 показать "такие" данные в select, при выборе пункта с vslue 2 "такие" и т.д. Проверку value делаете на jquery, например if($( "select option:selected" ).value() == 1) { //действие при выборе АХО}

Comment: Я прошу прошения, но я что то не могу догнать, вот у меня два select в первом у меня прописано АХО и CБ во втором select результаты которые должны отображаться так?

Comment: Ну здесь можно выводить пункты select из массива, например при выборе АХО будет выводить данные из массива №1, и т.д.

Comment: если помог, можете отметить как ответ